# How to display the contents of a file once uploaded

Tags: javascript, spring, jsp, file-upload

In my application I have a function in a jsp page which lets the user upload multiple files and it displays the list of all the files uploaded. My question is there a way that i can add a function so if the user clicks on the uploaded file it shows its contents in a window. Only pdfs and jpegs file types are allowed. I dont mind using javascript or if I need any type of API.  The sample code is below.  If you are not sure what im asking just add a comment and I will respond right away.

[image]

[image]

```
    <%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Spring MVC Multiple File Upload</title>
<script
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    //add more file components if Add is clicked
    $('#addFile').click(function() {
        var fileIndex = $('#fileTable tr').children().length - 1;
        $('#fileTable').append(
                '<tr><td>'+
                '   <input type="file" name="files['+ fileIndex +']" />'+
                '</td></tr>');
    });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Spring Multiple File Upload example</h1>

<form:form method="post" action="save.html"
        modelAttribute="uploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <p>Select files to upload. Press Add button to add more file inputs.</p>

    <input id="addFile" type="button" value="Add File" />
    <table id="fileTable">
        <tr>
            <td><input name="files[0]" type="file" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input name="files[1]" type="file" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <br/><input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its called a simple link. Either link to the file itself or to a servlet that loads the file byte by byte and writes it out to the response.  You can't control whether a PDF will display in the browser window or open Acrobat or whatever 3rd party tool the user has for PDFs, because that depends on the settings the user has on their PDF browser plugin if they even have one. If they don't have one, they will get a download prompt.  The only way you could ensure it opens in the browser itself were if you had your own Flash app to load the PDF in the browser window, and in that case too, if the user didn't have Flash, it wouldn't work.